# Trying to do camera motion-track, python-error in clip.py

Tags: error, motion-capture

after a long pause with motion-tracking (did this in old 2.xx-versions), i wanted to use this with my better camera and better footage on a new blender 3.3.0.
The calculation works as it did before, i get an error of about 1.9 px, looks well.
But when i try to Setup the tracking scene, it leads to an error

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.3/scripts/startup/bl_operators/clip.py", line 973, in execute
    self._setupCamera(context)
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.3/scripts/startup/bl_operators/clip.py", line 606, in _setupCamera
    cam.sensor_width = tracking.camera.sensor_width
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sensor_width'
```

Any hints how i can get oround this error? I am using bleder on an arch-linux.
The file shows this:

```
def _setupCamera(context):
        sc = context.space_data
        clip = sc.clip
        tracking = clip.tracking

        camob = CLIP_OT_setup_tracking_scene._findOrCreateCamera(context)
        cam = camob.data

        # Remove all constraints to be sure motion is fine.
        camob.constraints.clear()

        # Append camera solver constraint.
        con = camob.constraints.new(type='CAMERA_SOLVER')
        con.use_active_clip = True
        con.influence = 1.0

        cam.sensor_width = tracking.camera.sensor_width
        cam.lens = tracking.camera.focal_length
```

Thanks for your hints

Hartmut

Answer (score 0):

There have been some updates to blender in the near future.
I restarted the project once more, with the same footage, all was the same. And this time the building of the scene funtioned as expected.
So it seems to be an error that was erased by updates, or i did something different in the first try and made something wrong.
for me this case is closed. I will ad an other question dealing with shadow catchers, cause they are the thing now... :)